# Display Boolean on Vuetify dataTable

Tags: vue.js, datatable, vuetify.js

I made a data table with vue vuetify and I fetch my data from my api server.
In my table, everything is display except boolean.

Can you help me to see clearer

Table component

```
<template>
    <v-data-table
            :headers="headers"
            :items="fixture"
            :items-per-page="5"
            class="elevation-10"
    >

    </v-data-table>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'my_fixtures',
        props: ['fixture'],
        data () {
            return {
                headers: [
                    { text: 'name',value: 'name'},
                    { text: 'State', value: 'on' },
                    { text: 'Group', value: 'group' },
                    { text: 'Recipe', value: 'recipe' },
                    { text: 'start', value: 'startDate' },
                    { text: 'end', value: 'endDate' },
                    { text: 'Action', value: 'action' },
                ],
                items: this.fixtures

            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

In the object that I receive , the key 'on' is a Boolean.
I have all display , but nothing in the 'on' column

and this is what I do with props

```
<template>
    <v-container>
        <my_fixtures v-bind:fixture="fixtures"></my_fixtures>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
    import my_fixtures from "./greenhouse/fixtures";
    export default {
        name: "my_client",
        data: function (){
            return {fixtures: []}
        },
        components: {my_fixtures},
        mounted() {
                http.get('fixture/client')
                    .then(result => {
                        this.fixtures = result;
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                    console.error(error);
                });
        }
    }
</script>
```

[image: Here the result Object]

Comment: What does the response from `fixture/client` look like?  

If you just print out `{{ props.fixtures}}` in the items slot, what do you see?

Comment: If I comment All the template with slot , I have the same thing, I  thaink it works without slot

Comment: I update my post with image of object fixture/client

Answer (score 0):

Process and print data using methods.

try this.

```html
<td class="text-xs-right">{{ computedOn(props.fixture.on) }}</td>
```

```
export default {
  methods: {
    computedOn (value) {
      return String(value)
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Modifying original data due to vuetify bug
https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/8554

```
export default {
  mounted() {
    http.get('fixture/client')
      .then(result => {
        this.fixtures = result.map(value => {
          value.on = String(value.on)
        })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I have the same result, it' weird because when I comment the template slot , it's working the same. Can you have a best practice to display props value on data table ?

Comment: I believed that what I expected would work normally. However, after testing, I had a problem and searched for vuetify. (https://codepen.io/kdydesign/pen/poovaXa?editors=1010)
As a result, one bug report was found. https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/8554

Comment: However, it seems possible if 'on' of raw data is processed into 'String' and substituted for 'this.fixtures = result'. I have updated the answer, so I hope you will try it.

Comment: But can I fetch the data on my api on table component or main component and pass it through v-bind?. I'll test it tomorrow. Thanks

Comment: Changing mounted() to created() would be possible.

Comment: Nothing works for me , but one question, where is the best to call api ( which component) ? I call it on main component of client folder and I pass the props on the table component.

Comment: maybe it's a problem with the slots